# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 16: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to upload a csv from a url but i get the following error:
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x82 in position 16: invalid start byte

The code is as follows:

```
url = "http://www.akyokus.com/COE-101-Grades.xlsx"
pd.read_csv(url)
```

What can i do to solve this issue?

Comment: Uhm you're trying to read an XLSX with a function that is only able to read CSV files. That won't work. You need a library to read Excel files, or convert that file to CSV using Excel or some other spreadsheet program first.

Comment: `xlsx` isn't text. It's a ZIP file containing XML files. Pandas can already read `xlsx` fiels with `read_excel`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file is xlsx so `pd.read_excel` should work

```
url = "http://www.akyokus.com/COE-101-Grades.xlsx"

pd.read_excel(url)
```